# Query Parameters are not getting mapped

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, builder

I have a `REST` endpoint as shown below.

```
@Path("/consumers")
@Produces("application/x.com.abc.pqr.audit.v2+json")
@Consumes("application/x.com.abc.pqr.audit.v2+json")
public interface ConsumerEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Path("paged")
    Page<Module> getConsumersOfDependencyByPage(@BeanParam ConsumerQueryParams params);

}
```

As you can see above, I am using `@BeanParam` to map the query parameters passed from the front end side.

The `ConsumerQueryParams` class is shown below.

```
public class ConsumerQueryParams implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6440255704974023223L;

    @QueryParam("pageNum") @DefaultValue("1") private int pageNum;
    @QueryParam("pageSize") @DefaultValue("25") private int pageSize;
    @QueryParam("groupId") private String groupId;
    @QueryParam("artifactId") private String artifactId;
    @QueryParam("version") private String version;
    @QueryParam("groupIdFilter") private String groupIdFilter;
    @QueryParam("artifactIdFilter") private String artifactIdFilter;
    @QueryParam("versionFilter") private String versionFilter;

    public ConsumerQueryParams() {
    }

    private ConsumerQueryParams(Builder builder) {
        this.pageNum = builder.pageNum;
        this.pageSize = builder.pageSize;
        this.groupId = builder.groupId;
        this.artifactId = builder.artifactId;
        this.version = builder.version;
        this.groupIdFilter = builder.groupIdFilter;
        this.artifactIdFilter = builder.artifactIdFilter;
        this.versionFilter = builder.versionFilter;
    }

    public int getPageNum() {
        return pageNum;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public String getArtifactId() {
        return artifactId;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public String getGroupIdFilter() {
        return groupIdFilter;
    }

    public String getArtifactIdFilter() {
        return artifactIdFilter;
    }

    public String getVersionFilter() {
        return versionFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof ConsumerQueryParams))
            return false;
        ConsumerQueryParams other = (ConsumerQueryParams) obj;
        return Objects.equals(pageNum, other.pageNum) &&
                Objects.equals(pageSize, other.pageSize) &&
                Objects.equals(groupId, other.groupId) &&
                Objects.equals(artifactId, other.artifactId) &&
                Objects.equals(version, other.version) &&
                Objects.equals(groupIdFilter, other.groupIdFilter) &&
                Objects.equals(artifactIdFilter, other.artifactIdFilter) &&
                Objects.equals(versionFilter, other.versionFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(pageNum, pageSize, groupId, artifactId, version, groupIdFilter, artifactIdFilter, versionFilter);
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private int pageNum;
        private int pageSize;
        private String groupId;
        private String artifactId;
        private String version;
        private String groupIdFilter;
        private String artifactIdFilter;
        private String versionFilter;

        public Builder(int pageNum, int pageSize, String groupId, String artifactId) {
            Preconditions.checkArgument(pageNum > 0, "pageNum must be greater than 0.");
            Preconditions.checkArgument(pageSize > 0, "pageSize must be greater than 0.");
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(groupId, "groupId is null");
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(artifactId, "artifactId is null");

            this.pageNum = pageNum;
            this.pageSize = pageSize;
            this.groupId = groupId;
            this.artifactId = artifactId;
        }

        public Builder setVersion(String version) {
            this.version = version;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setGroupIdFilter(String groupIdFilter) {
            this.groupIdFilter = groupIdFilter;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setArtifactIdFilter(String artifactIdFilter) {
            this.artifactIdFilter = artifactIdFilter;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setVersionFilter(String versionFilter) {
            this.versionFilter = versionFilter;
            return this;
        }

        public ConsumerQueryParams build() {
            return new ConsumerQueryParams(this);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that I am using the `Builder` pattern to set the variables.
I am using the below url to access the above specified endpoint.

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/consumers/paged?groupId=org.slf4j&artifactId=slf4j-api&groupIdFilter=sdlc
```

Everything works fine. I am able to get the data on `Postman` successfully.
Now I have a requirement where I need to rename the `groupIdFilter`, `artifactIdFilter`, `versionFilter` query params in `ConsumerQueryParams` class to `consumerGroupIdFilter`, `consumerArtifactIdFilter` and `consumerVersionFilter` respectively.
After changing the variable names in `ConsumerQueryParams` class, it looks like this:

```
public class ConsumerQueryParams implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6440255704974023223L;

    @QueryParam("pageNum") @DefaultValue("1") private int pageNum;
    @QueryParam("pageSize") @DefaultValue("25") private int pageSize;
    @QueryParam("groupId") private String groupId;
    @QueryParam("artifactId") private String artifactId;
    @QueryParam("version") private String version;
    @QueryParam("groupIdFilter") private String consumerGroupIdFilter;
    @QueryParam("artifactIdFilter") private String consumerArtifactIdFilter;
    @QueryParam("versionFilter") private String consumerVersionFilter;

    public ConsumerQueryParams() {
    }

    private ConsumerQueryParams(Builder builder) {
        this.pageNum = builder.pageNum;
        this.pageSize = builder.pageSize;
        this.groupId = builder.groupId;
        this.artifactId = builder.artifactId;
        this.version = builder.version;
        this.consumerGroupIdFilter = builder.consumerGroupIdFilter;
        this.consumerArtifactIdFilter = builder.consumerArtifactIdFilter;
        this.consumerVersionFilter = builder.consumerVersionFilter;
    }

    public int getPageNum() {
        return pageNum;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public String getArtifactId() {
        return artifactId;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public String getConsumerGroupIdFilter() {
        return consumerGroupIdFilter;
    }

    public String getConsumerArtifactIdFilter() {
        return consumerArtifactIdFilter;
    }

    public String getConsumerVersionFilter() {
        return consumerVersionFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof ConsumerQueryParams))
            return false;
        ConsumerQueryParams other = (ConsumerQueryParams) obj;
        return Objects.equals(pageNum, other.pageNum) &&
                Objects.equals(pageSize, other.pageSize) &&
                Objects.equals(groupId, other.groupId) &&
                Objects.equals(artifactId, other.artifactId) &&
                Objects.equals(version, other.version) &&
                Objects.equals(consumerGroupIdFilter, other.consumerGroupIdFilter) &&
                Objects.equals(consumerArtifactIdFilter, other.consumerArtifactIdFilter) &&
                Objects.equals(consumerVersionFilter, other.consumerVersionFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(pageNum, pageSize, groupId, artifactId, version, consumerGroupIdFilter, consumerArtifactIdFilter, consumerVersionFilter);
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private int pageNum;
        private int pageSize;
        private String groupId;
        private String artifactId;
        private String version;
        private String consumerGroupIdFilter;
        private String consumerArtifactIdFilter;
        private String consumerVersionFilter;

        public Builder(int pageNum, int pageSize, String groupId, String artifactId) {
            Preconditions.checkArgument(pageNum > 0, "pageNum must be greater than 0.");
            Preconditions.checkArgument(pageSize > 0, "pageSize must be greater than 0.");
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(groupId, "groupId is null");
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(artifactId, "artifactId is null");

            this.pageNum = pageNum;
            this.pageSize = pageSize;
            this.groupId = groupId;
            this.artifactId = artifactId;
        }

        public Builder setVersion(String version) {
            this.version = version;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setConsumerGroupIdFilter(String consumerGroupIdFilter) {
            this.consumerGroupIdFilter = consumerGroupIdFilter;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setConsumerArtifactIdFilter(String consumerArtifactIdFilter) {
            this.consumerArtifactIdFilter = consumerArtifactIdFilter;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setConsumerVersionFilter(String consumerVersionFilter) {
            this.consumerVersionFilter = consumerVersionFilter;
            return this;
        }

        public ConsumerQueryParams build() {
            return new ConsumerQueryParams(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to access the same endpoint with the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/consumers/paged?groupId=org.slf4j&artifactId=slf4j-api&consumerGroupIdFilter=sdlc
```

But this is not working. The `consumerGroupIdFilter` query param in the url is not being mapped to the `consumerGroupIdFilter` variable of the `ConsumerQueryParams` object, whereas `groupId` and `artifactId` gets mapped.
I am not sure why this is happening. As far as I know, the `ConsumerQueryParams` class has the correct code. All that I did was to change the variable names and updated the getters and setters in the `Builder` class.
Can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the url has the new name and the annotation has the old one

```
@QueryParam("groupIdFilter") 

consumerGroupIdFilter
```

Comment: I just found it myself buddy. Was just typing the answer and your answer popped up. Anyways, I still marked your answer as the correct one. :-)

Comment: No buddy. You deserve it. You spent time in looking into this. :-)